Zabbix discovery rules for item prototype
I have a task: without using scripts, I need to ping the IPMI interface of a host. By default, the check is performed on the first network interface. So, I decided to create a discovery rule that would allow performing a simple check -icmpping through the discovery of interfaces available on the host. To do this, I retrieve all interfaces via the API, but the item prototype does not trigger. The template is currently without any filters. At the very least, I want to make sure that simple check -icmpping items are created for all host interfaces. However, they are not being created.
  version: '7.0'
  template_groups:
    - uuid: 7df96b18c230490a9a0a9e2307226338
      name: Templates
  templates:
    - uuid: e29a8d45cdca42d5a4f2c596d821fd88
      template: ipmipingtool
      name: ipmipingtool
      groups:
        - name: Templates
      items:
        - uuid: 7001e17e1f6c418c9d6b21a2400b8232
          name: ip_main
          type: HTTP_AGENT
          key: ip.main
          value_type: TEXT
          trends: '0'
          preprocessing:
            - type: JSONPATH
              parameters:
                - '$.result[*].ip'
          url: 'http://zabbix.example.com/api_jsonrpc.php'
          posts: |
            {
                "jsonrpc": "2.0",
                "method": "hostinterface.get",
                "params": {
                    "output": "extend"
            
                },
                "auth": "token",
                "id": 1
            }
          headers:
            - name: Content-Type
              value: application/json
      discovery_rules:
        - uuid: 38b1285f913b469ebf11bb9b0ad1618f
          name: ip_lld
          type: DEPENDENT
          key: ip.lld
          delay: '0'
          item_prototypes:
            - uuid: c15181931db3446cb8120cdd6b0d9475
              name: '{#ADDR}'
              type: SIMPLE
              key: 'icmpping[{#ADDR}]'
          master_item:
            key: ip.main
          lld_macro_paths:
            - lld_macro: '{#ADDR}'
              path: '$.[*]'
          preprocessing:
            - type: JSONPATH
              parameters:
                - '$.[*]' 


Item name: ip_main - It returns this information.
["127.0.0.1","192.168.1.111","192.168.1.92","192.168.1.93","192.168.1.95","192.168.1.117","192.168.1.88","192.168.1.65","192.168.1.76","192.168.1.111","192.168.1.88"]
After that, I send it to the discovery rules. I have changed the preprocessing steps and tried different JSON paths, but it doesn't affect the result. What is wrong?
